# SQL insert into statement using select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have a table, Table1, with 7 columns. Lets name them C1 to C7.

Columns C3-C6 allow for NULL values.

How do I write a SQL insert statement into Table1 that will grab the values for C1, and C2 from a different table (ReferenceTable), while setting C7 to the value 0?

Right now, I have the following:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (C1, C2)
SELECT @C1, C2
FROM ReferenceTable
```

This does almost everything I need, except for initializing C7 with the value 0. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: It is a poor practice to write INSERT statements that do not include every column (except identity columns).  Also, you could make C7 have a default of 0 and make it `NOT NULL`.  Then when you do not include it in your INSERT statement, it would default to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append the 0 to the `SELECT`...

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (C1, C2, C7)
SELECT C1, C2, 0
FROM ReferenceTable
```

or, you can set `C7` to have a **default** value of 0, which would be my **preferred** option.

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 
ALTER COLUMN C7 SET DEFAULT (0)
```

So, `C7` will always be 0 if nothing is inserted.

You'll see this in the designer (within Management Studio), when you modify a table, the field you are looking for is *Default Value or Binding*

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use this insert query:

```
insert into table1 (c1,c2,c7) (select c1,c2,0 from reftable)
```